# Proper way to use condition between component and function

Tags: reactjs, function, if-statement, constants

what is the best way to use conditional between redux component and function. Tryed to google. but without any luck

```
const Page = (awesomeValue) => {
 if(awesomeValue) {
    SendRequest()
  } else {
    <Component title={'my awesome title'} />=
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 best ways i would do it

1.

```
{
  return (
   <>
     {awesomeValue && sendRequest()}
     {!awesomeValue && <Component/>}
   </>
  )
}
```

2. 

```
{
  if(awesomeValue){
    sendRequest();
    return;
  }

  return <Component/>
}
```

First option is very clean but won't be very good with even slightly more complex operations needed

I try avoid using `else` unless I have to

Comment: thanks, very nice solution